# Why run native exe from byte array example don't work for me?

Tags: c#, arrays, ram, native-code

I found some questions, asking how to run native EXE from RAM. I used this example code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/* 
 * Title: CMemoryExecute.cs
 * Description: Runs an EXE in memory using native WinAPI. Very optimized and tiny.
 * 
 * Developed by: affixiate 
 * Release date: December 10, 2010
 * Released on: http://opensc.ws
 * Credits:
 *          MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com)
 *          NtInternals (http://undocumented.ntinternals.net)
 *          Pinvoke (http://pinvoke.net)
 *          
 * Comments: If you use this code, I require you to give me credits. Don't be a ripper! ;]
 */

// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
public static unsafe class CMemoryExecute
{
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public uint cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public uint dwX;
        public uint dwY;
        public uint dwXSize;
        public uint dwYSize;
        public uint dwXCountChars;
        public uint dwYCountChars;
        public uint dwFillAttribute;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs an EXE (which is loaded in a byte array) in memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exeBuffer">The EXE buffer.</param>
    /// <param name="hostProcess">Full path of the host process to run the buffer in.</param>
    /// <param name="optionalArguments">Optional command line arguments.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Run(byte[] exeBuffer, string hostProcess, string optionalArguments = "")
    {
        // STARTUPINFO
        STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

        var IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER = new byte[0x28]; // pish
        var IMAGE_NT_HEADERS = new byte[0xf8]; // pinh
        var IMAGE_DOS_HEADER = new byte[0x40]; // pidh
        var PROCESS_INFO = new int[0x4]; // pi
        var CONTEXT = new byte[0x2cc]; // ctx

        byte* pish;
        fixed (byte* p = &IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER[0])
            pish = p;

        byte* pinh;
        fixed (byte* p = &IMAGE_NT_HEADERS[0])
            pinh = p;

        byte* pidh;
        fixed (byte* p = &IMAGE_DOS_HEADER[0])
            pidh = p;

        byte* ctx;
        fixed (byte* p = &CONTEXT[0])
            ctx = p;

        // Set the flag.
        *(uint*)(ctx + 0x0 /* ContextFlags */) = CONTEXT_FULL;

        // Get the DOS header of the EXE.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(exeBuffer, 0, IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, 0, IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.Length);

        /* Sanity check:  See if we have MZ header. */
        if (*(ushort*)(pidh + 0x0 /* e_magic */) != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
            return false;

        var e_lfanew = *(int*)(pidh + 0x3c);

        // Get the NT header of the EXE.
        Buffer.BlockCopy(exeBuffer, e_lfanew, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, 0, IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.Length);

        /* Sanity check: See if we have PE00 header. */
        if (*(uint*)(pinh + 0x0 /* Signature */) != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
            return false;

        // Run with parameters if necessary.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalArguments))
            hostProcess += " " + optionalArguments;

        int ERROR_CODE = 0;

        if (!CreateProcess(null, hostProcess, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref StartupInfo, PROCESS_INFO))
        {
            ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            return false;
        }

        var ImageBase = new IntPtr(*(int*)(pinh + 0x34));
        NtUnmapViewOfSection((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, ImageBase);

        ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (VirtualAllocEx((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, ImageBase, *(uint*)(pinh + 0x50 /* SizeOfImage */), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE) == IntPtr.Zero)
            Run(exeBuffer, hostProcess, optionalArguments); // Memory allocation failed; try again (this can happen in low memory situations)

        fixed (byte* p = &exeBuffer[0])
            NtWriteVirtualMemory((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, ImageBase, (IntPtr)p, *(uint*)(pinh + 84 /* SizeOfHeaders */), IntPtr.Zero);

        ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        for (ushort i = 0; i < *(ushort*)(pinh + 0x6 /* NumberOfSections */); i++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(exeBuffer, e_lfanew + IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.Length + (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.Length * i), IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER, 0, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.Length);
            fixed (byte* p = &exeBuffer[*(uint*)(pish + 0x14 /* PointerToRawData */)])
                NtWriteVirtualMemory((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, (IntPtr)((int)ImageBase + *(uint*)(pish + 0xc /* VirtualAddress */)), (IntPtr)p, *(uint*)(pish + 0x10 /* SizeOfRawData */), IntPtr.Zero);

            ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }

        NtGetContextThread((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[1] /* pi.hThread */, (IntPtr)ctx);

        ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        NtWriteVirtualMemory((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[0] /* pi.hProcess */, (IntPtr)(*(uint*)(ctx + 0xAC /* ecx */)), ImageBase, 0x4, IntPtr.Zero);

        ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        *(uint*)(ctx + 0xB0 /* eax */) = (uint)ImageBase + *(uint*)(pinh + 0x28 /* AddressOfEntryPoint */);
        NtSetContextThread((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[1] /* pi.hThread */, (IntPtr)ctx);

        ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        NtResumeThread((IntPtr)PROCESS_INFO[1] /* pi.hThread */, IntPtr.Zero);

        ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        return true;
    }

    #region WinNT Definitions

    private const uint CONTEXT_FULL = 0x10007;
    private const int CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x4;
    private const int MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;
    private const int MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000;
    private const int PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
    private const ushort IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE = 0x5A4D; // MZ
    private const uint IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE = 0x00004550; // PE00

    private static short SW_SHOW = 5;
    private static short SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const uint STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
    private const uint STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;


    #region WinAPI
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, int[] lpProcessInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint NtUnmapViewOfSection(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int NtWriteVirtualMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint nSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int NtGetContextThread(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr lpContext);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int NtSetContextThread(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr lpContext);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint NtResumeThread(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr SuspendCount);
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

My .net prog was in 32 bit architecture and I was injecting into C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vbc.exe:

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "EXE Files (*.exe)|*.exe;";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        CMemoryExecute.Run(File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName), "C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\vbc.exe");
```

When I run this, simply happens nothing, but the vbc.exe actually starts and visible in task manager, but hidden. I tried to inject into other exes too.

I use 32 bit win 8 and tried to run notepad.exe and some other win32 exe.
No any windows internal errors appear, like DEP prevention and etc.

I added **ERROR_CODE = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();** code checks into the code, but everywhere it is zero, kind of no errors and no work :(

I tested in framework 2.0 and 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I should mention that I don't know much about what this code is doing, but see this line:

```
StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

Nowhere else is wShowWindow assigned to.

I attempted to visit http://opensc.ws which is mentioned in the comment, and got a strange page asking for a captcha and a reason for temporary access. Permanent access needed site admin approval. After requesting "temporary" access, I got a message saying the website was offline. Very suspicious.

I would place money that this code was originally developed with intentions other than good, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Usually all "bad" code can be used for making reverse engineering more hard, to protect your soft from hackers. In my case, my boss gave me a crazy task, which he don't understand what means. I need to make third party program to ask for license and do not run on other PCs, where it not licensed. So, I thought, the eases way is to encrypt this prog and build in my prog, then decrypt it when needed and run. Of course, I don't have sources of other prog and it's developer will not do anything for me.

Comment: Were you able to get your process to display a window?

Comment: No. After some attempts the host process stopped spawning at all :( I think that everything is file with SW_HIDE, I don't need to show process where I inject my own. This is where I grabbed this example: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/24348-C-Run-non-NET-exe-from-memory

Comment: Looks like the types of executables you can run with this are pretty limited. Interesting problem, but I would think this would be too fragile to use in a real product anyway. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for attempt to help.